# What do the letters on this LEGO Drum Machine indicate?

Tags: drum-kits, drum-machine

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlaY8kSTO28&t=300s&pp=ygUdYnJpY2sgdGVjaG5vbG9neSBkcnVtIG1hY2hpbmU%3D) by Brick Technology, they make a LEGO drum machine. It works a bit like a music box, with a set of eleven piezoelectric drum pickups each actuated by its own Technic-built drum stick.  These sticks are labeled, in order,

> `KSHCTTTRCAA`

and I can't for the life of me figure out what all the letters means.

I'm familiar enough with drums (and can hear well enough to figure out) that K is for the Kick (or bass) drum, S is for the Snare drum and H is for the Hi-hat. Some investigation into the matter indicates the the three T's are most likely for the three Toms, with the two C's for the Crash cymbals and the R for the Ride cymbal, but I am not as confident with this assessment. And I can find nothing to determine what the two A's are for - are they just "Auxiliary" percussion, or is there some part of the kit that starts with A?

Answer (score 2):

There's a clue around the 2:00 mark. Activating an A trigger makes a different percussion sound. There will be many other different sounds available from the module, activated by, actually, any of the triggers.

They could be cowbell, guiro, quickly closed hi-hat, wood block, tambourine, choked cymbal, triangle, to name just a few. So, yes, auxiliary is most likely what A represents, and those will be the sounds that would get changed most frequently, as all the others constitute the basic drum kit.

A *very* clever and impressive idea..!